# How to fetch the entire div rather than inner content of that?

Tags: jquery

In case the item exists i am fetching the HTML as `<h3>First Item</h3>`

Is it possible to fetch the entire HTML

```
 <div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap703" data-lastwrapquan="0">
         <h3>First Item</h3>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fpzeLa0a/6/

Comment: do you mean get `<h3>First Item</h3>` not just `First Item`

Comment: I mean not just <h3>First Item</h3> , but the entire  <div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap703" data-lastwrapquan="0">
         <h3>First Item</h3>
    </div>

Comment: .parent().html()  is fetching me the entire content inside the mycontainer , how to get only the matching one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.prop('outerHTML')` instead of `.html()`.

This will return a string of the html inclusive of the tag.

Comment: The result i am getting [div#lastwrap703.lastItm_Wrap, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, jquery: "2.1.0", constructor: function, selector: ""…] , how can i convert that to HTML ?

Answer (score 2):

You could take your element, clone it, wrap it into a div, select the newly created parent element and get its html content.

```
  var htmldata = $("selector").clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html()
   console.log(htmldata);
  }
```

In your specific case the selector will be `"#mycontainer #lastwrap" + id[i]`